# Axios post method: There is error Error: Request failed with status code 405

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, httprequest

I have a simple registration form that the user can register in my app, now I want to send submitted data to another service.

First I test my request using postman as follows using a raw option in a postman panel.

Api url : `app3.salesmanago.pl/api/contact/upsert`

```
JSON DATA:
{
  "clientId":"w2ncrw06k7ny45umsssc",
  "apiKey":"ssssj2q8qp4fbp9qf2b8p49fz",
  "requestTime":1327056031488,
  "sha":"ba0ddddddb543dcaf5ca82b09e33264fedb509cfb4806c",
  "async" : true,
  "owner" : "adam@rce.com",
  "contact" : { 
        "email" : "test-1@konri.com",
        "name" : "Test",
        "address":{
            "streetAddress":"Brzyczynska 123",
      }
    }
}
```

I get the following success result

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": [],
    "contactId": "b52910be-9d22-4830-82d5-c9dc788888ba",
    "externalId": null
}
```

Now in my localhost, I am testing sending data to API using react js with `Axios post` method, as follow

```
// send data to sales manago
const sendSalesManagoData = () =>{
var current_timestamp = Date.now();
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'app3.salesmanago.pl/api/contact/upsert',
        data: {
            clientId    : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            apiKey      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            sha         : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            requestTime :  current_timestamp,
            owner       : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            contact:{
                user_id : user.id,
                email   : user.email,
                name    : `${user.first_name} ${user.last_name}`,
                industryType: companyIndustry,
            }   
        },
        headers: {
            'Accept'       : 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        },

        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log('there is error', error);
    });
}
```

Now when I send data I get the following error.

```
(405 methods not allowed) there is error Error: Request failed with status code 405
```

[image]

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Maybe this is a CORS related issue with your service? Postman doesn't behave like a Browser.

Comment: seems like this is a backend issue. You need to allow post method for this endpoint from  backend

Comment: The `POST` method is not supported on your backend application. Make sure to double-check the backend app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow CORS on your server.

[Here is more information about CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Answer (score -1):

You have missed the `http://` or `https://` prefix from the URL.

Change the line

```
url: 'app3.salesmanago.pl/api/contact/upsert',
```

to

```
url: 'https://app3.salesmanago.pl/api/contact/upsert',
```

When axios is used as a function, it tries to understand the url

- if it starts with `http://` or `https://` it uses the url as is
- if it does not start, with `http://` or `https://`, then axios will append it to the current url

EDIT:
Yan can use `axios.post()` instead.